# How many time can you fit one array to a specific size array (python)

Tags: python, arrays, random

I want to create a randomized array that contains another array few times,
So if:

```
Big_Array = np.zeroes(5,5)
Inner_array = no.array([[1,1,1],
                        [2,1,2]])
```

And if we want 2 Inner_array it could look like:

```
Big_Array = [[1,2,0,0,0], 
             [1,1,0,0,0], 
             [1,2,0,0,0], 
             [0,0,2,1,2], 
             [0,0,1,1,1]]
```

I would like to write a code that will
A. Tell whether the bigger array can fit the required amount of inner arrays, and
B. place randomly the inner array (in random rotations) x amount of times in the big array without overlap
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you'd like to sample valid tilings of a square which contain a specified amount of integral-sided rectangles.

This is a [special case of the exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Pentomino_tiling), which is NP-complete, so in general I'd expect there to be no really efficient solutions, but you could solve it using [Knuth's algorithm x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X). It would take a while to code yourself though.

There are also a few implementations of DLX online, such as [this one from code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233300/solving-pentomino-puzzles-by-using-knuths-algorithm-x) (not sure what the copyright on that is though).